# Failed to load texture on action detected

Tags: android, object, textures, augmented-reality, image

So i have an app that when it sees an particularly pictures, it set some actions. And a picture should appear on the screen (it does not). When you click on that picture, it starts an video.
The video works fine, all i have to do is touch the screen and it starts.
There is something I'm missing because the picture is not loading.
I get one ERROR in Logcat and is something like this:

```
 08-29 10:15:44.102: E/libEGL(2314): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
```

**CODE:**
This is instantiated when i run the program:
The model is not a billboard so it skips that part and goes on to loading the texture.

```
private boolean mLoadGeometry(MetaioModel model, String assetsDirectoryPath) {
    // String modelName = model.name;
    // MetaioModel model = getModelForName(modelName);
    if (model != null) {
        LogService.log(TAG, "object : " + model.model);
        if (model.model == null) {
            if ((model.isBillboard != null) && model.isBillboard) {
                loadBillboard(entity.absolutePath + "/" + model.texture, model);
                LogService.log(TAG, "LoadBillboard : " + model.texture);
            } else {

                LogService.log(TAG, " model.geometryFile : " + model.file);
                if (model.file != null) {
                    String modelPath = assetsDirectoryPath + "/" + model.file /* + ".md2" */;
                    model.model = mMobileSDK.loadGeometry(modelPath);
                    LogService.log(TAG, "> Loaded model: " + modelPath);
                    if (model.model != null) {
                        LogService.log(TAG, "> model.texture: " + model.texture);
                        if ((model.texture != null) && !"".equals(model.texture)) {
                            LogService.log(TAG, "Setting texture = " + entity.absolutePath + "/" + model.texture);
                            model.model.setTexture(entity.absolutePath + "/" + model.texture);
                            LogService.log(TAG, "Texture set");

                        }
                        LogService.log(TAG, "[Loaded geometry] model.model = " + model.model);
                    } else {
                        LogService.log(TAG, "[Load geometry] object is null");
                    }
                } else {
                    LogService.log(TAG, "> model.geometryFile is NULL");
                }
            }
            boolean success = setModelProperties(model, assetsDirectoryPath);
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This is how the `SetModelProperties` function look like:

```
private boolean setModelProperties(MetaioModel metaioModel, String assetsDirectoryPath) {
    LogService.log(TAG, "[MetaioModel] "+ metaioModel +"-----texture"+ metaioModel.texture);
    if (metaioModel == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        IUnifeyeMobileGeometry object = metaioModel.model;
        if (object != null) {
            if (metaioModel.translate != null) {
                if (metaioModel.translate.length == 3) {
                    Vector3d vector3d = new Vector3d(metaioModel.translate[0], metaioModel.translate[1], metaioModel.translate[2]);
                    object.setMoveTranslation(vector3d);
                    LogService.log(TAG, "[Properties] translate set");
                } else {
                    LogService.log(TAG, "[ERROR] setModelProperties : translate ---> Vector is of wrong size !!!");
                }
            }
            if (metaioModel.scale != null) {
                if (metaioModel.scale.length == 3) {
                    Vector3d vector3d = new Vector3d(metaioModel.scale[0], metaioModel.scale[1], metaioModel.scale[2]);
                    object.setMoveScale(vector3d);
                    LogService.log(TAG, "[Properties] scale3 set");
                } else {
                    LogService.log(TAG, "[ERROR] setModelProperties : scale ---> Vector is of wrong size !!!");
                }
            }
            if (metaioModel.rotate != null) {
                if (metaioModel.rotate.length == 3) {
                    Vector3d vector3d = new Vector3d(metaioModel.rotate[0], metaioModel.rotate[1], metaioModel.rotate[2]);
                    object.setMoveRotation(vector3d);
                    LogService.log(TAG, "[Properties] rotate3 set");
                } else if (metaioModel.rotate.length == 4) {
                    Vector4d vector4d = new Vector4d(metaioModel.rotate[0], metaioModel.rotate[1], metaioModel.rotate[2], metaioModel.rotate[3]);
                    object.setMoveRotation(vector4d);
                    LogService.log(TAG, "[Properties] rotate4 set");
                } else {
                    LogService.log(TAG, "[ERROR] setModelProperties : rotate ---> Vector is of wrong size !!!");
                }
            }
            if (metaioModel.visible != null) {
                object.setVisible(metaioModel.visible);
                LogService.log(TAG, "[Properties] visibility set to : " + metaioModel.visible);
            }

            if (metaioModel.occlude != null) {
                object.setOcclusionMode(metaioModel.occlude);
                LogService.log(TAG, "[Properties] occlusion set to : " + metaioModel.occlude);
            }
            if (metaioModel.picking != null) {
                object.setPickingEnabled(metaioModel.picking);
                LogService.log(TAG, "[Properties] is pickable set to : " + metaioModel.picking);
            }

            if (metaioModel.xray != null) {
                object.setRenderAsXray(metaioModel.xray);
                LogService.log(TAG, "[Properties] xray set to : " + metaioModel.xray);
            }

            if (metaioModel.transparency != null) {
                int transparency = metaioModel.transparency;
                object.setTransparency((short) transparency);
                LogService.log(TAG, "[Properties] transparency set to : " + transparency);
            }

            if (metaioModel.texture != null) {
                object.setTexture(entity.absolutePath + "/" + metaioModel.texture);
                object.setVisible(true);

                LogService.log(TAG, "[Properties] Rendered set to : "+object.getIsRendered());
                LogService.log(TAG, "[Properties] Visibility set to : "+object.getIsVisible());
                LogService.log(TAG, "[Properties] texture set to : " + entity.absolutePath + "/" + metaioModel.texture);
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The object is not null, and it should enter in scale and texture. (LogCat status of it):

```
 -28 12:12:36.096: I/AugmentedRealityActivity(5910): ==> model : MetaioModel [name=movie, file=square.md2, isBillboard=null, translate=null, scale=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], rotate=null, visible=null, occlude=null, picking=null, xray=null, transparency=null, texture=start.png, movie_texture=null, billboard=null, defaultTexture=null, geometryFile=null]
```

The setAction class that changes the visibility:

```
private void setActions(ArrayList<Action> actions, String directory) {
    if ((actions != null) && (actions.size() > 0)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < actions.size(); i++) {
            String type = actions.get(i).type;
            Action action = actions.get(i);
            LogService.log(TAG, "==> action Type : " + type);

            if ("saveScreenshot".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                LogService.log(TAG, "==> saveScreenshot");
                captureScreenShot(entity.absolutePath + "/Screenshots/screenshot.jpg");
            }
 else if ("setTexture".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                LogService.log(TAG, "==> setTexture");
                String modelName = action.model;
                if ((modelName != null) && (modelName.length() > 0)) {
                    LogService.log(TAG, "InSetTEXTURE======Inainte de Texture set: " + action.file);
                    String texture = action.file;
                    if (texture.length() > 0) {
                        String texturePath = entity.absolutePath + "/" + texture;
                        MetaioModel metaioModel = getModelForName(modelName);
                        IUnifeyeMobileGeometry object = metaioModel.model;
                        if (object != null) {
                            object.setTexture(texturePath);
                            // flag = !flag;
                            // System.out.println("flag = " + flag);
                            // object.setTexture("changed.jpg", null, true);

                            // object.setTexture(entity.absolutePath + "/" + model.texture);
                            // if (flag) {
                            // } else {
                            // object.setTexture(entity.absolutePath + "/normal.png" /* + model.texture */);
                            // }

                            LogService.log(TAG, "InSetTEXTURE======Texture set: " + texturePath);
                        } else {
                            LogService.log(TAG, "ERROR: object is null!");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

All Logcat LOG:

```
08-28 12:12:33.846: I/AugmentedRealityActivity(5910): >> Tracking data: /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.cardemotion.mobile/files/VWSEEMORE/TEMP/movie_texture/TrackingData_MarkerlessFast.xml
08-28 12:12:33.846: I/AugmentedRealityActivity(5910): >> AugmentedRealityActivity.onCreate()
08-28 12:12:36.056: I/AugmentedRealityActivity(5910): > Loading assets from : /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.cardemotion.mobile/files/VWSEEMORE/TEMP/movie_texture
08-28 12:12:36.056: I/AugmentedRealityActivity(5910): ==> action Type : loadGeometry
08-28 12:12:36.056: I/AugmentedRealityActivity(5910): ==> load geometry
08-28 12:12:36.056: I/AugmentedRealityActivity(5910): object : null
08-28 12:12:36.056: I/AugmentedRealityActivity(5910):  model.geometryFile : square.md2
08-28 12:12:36.066: I/AugmentedRealityActivity(5910): > Loaded model: /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.cardemotion.mobile/files/VWSEEMORE/TEMP/movie_texture/square.md2
08-28 12:12:36.066: I/AugmentedRealityActivity(5910): > model.texture: start.png
08-28 12:12:36.066: I/AugmentedRealityActivity(5910): Setting texture = /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.cardemotion.mobile/files/VWSEEMORE/TEMP/movie_texture/start.png
08-28 12:12:36.086: I/AugmentedRealityActivity(5910): Texture set
08-28 12:12:36.086: I/AugmentedRealityActivity(5910): [Loaded geometry] model.model = com.metaio.unifeye.ndk.IUnifeyeMobileGeometry@4af880
08-28 12:12:36.086: I/AugmentedRealityActivity(5910): [MetaioModel] MetaioModel [name=movie, file=square.md2, isBillboard=null, translate=null, scale=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], rotate=null, visible=null, occlude=null, picking=null, xray=null, transparency=null, texture=start.png, movie_texture=null, billboard=null, defaultTexture=null, geometryFile=null]-----texturestart.png
08-28 12:12:36.096: I/AugmentedRealityActivity(5910): [Properties] scale3 set
08-28 12:12:36.096: I/AugmentedRealityActivity(5910): [Properties] Rendered set to : false
08-28 12:12:36.096: I/AugmentedRealityActivity(5910): [Properties] Visibility set to : true
08-28 12:12:36.096: I/AugmentedRealityActivity(5910): [Properties] texture set to : /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.cardemotion.mobile/files/VWSEEMORE/TEMP/movie_texture/start.png
08-28 12:12:36.096: I/AugmentedRealityActivity(5910): ==> action Type : setMovieTexture
08-28 12:12:36.096: I/AugmentedRealityActivity(5910): ==> setMovieTexture
08-28 12:12:36.096: I/AugmentedRealityActivity(5910): ==> setMovieTexture modelName : movie
08-28 12:12:36.096: I/AugmentedRealityActivity(5910): Got 1 models
08-28 12:12:36.096: I/AugmentedRealityActivity(5910): Returning model : movie
08-28 12:12:36.096: I/AugmentedRealityActivity(5910): ==> model : MetaioModel [name=movie, file=square.md2, isBillboard=null, translate=null, scale=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], rotate=null, visible=null, occlude=null, picking=null, xray=null, transparency=null, texture=start.png, movie_texture=null, billboard=null, defaultTexture=null, geometryFile=null]
08-28 12:12:36.116: I/AugmentedRealityActivity(5910): set movie texture : /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.cardemotion.mobile/files/VWSEEMORE/TEMP/movie_texture/demo_movie.3g2,false,true
```

LogCat when Marker is detected and should set texture to visible:

```
08-28 12:17:01.926: I/AugmentedRealityActivity(5910): >> Marker detected..
08-28 12:17:01.926: I/System.out(5910): >> cosName patch1
08-28 12:17:01.926: I/AugmentedRealityActivity(5910): Action size in action!=null  ----1/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.cardemotion.mobile/files/VWSEEMORE/TEMP/movie_texture
08-28 12:17:01.926: I/AugmentedRealityActivity(5910): ==> action Type : setVisible
08-28 12:17:01.926: I/AugmentedRealityActivity(5910): ==> setVisible
08-28 12:17:01.926: I/AugmentedRealityActivity(5910): Got 1 models
08-28 12:17:01.926: I/AugmentedRealityActivity(5910): Returning model : movie
08-28 12:17:01.926: I/AugmentedRealityActivity(5910): ==> modelName: movie setVisible : true
08-28 12:17:01.926: I/AugmentedRealityActivity(5910): Devine Visible==> modelName: movie true  object is object: com.metaio.unifeye.ndk.IUnifeyeMobileGeometry@4af880texturecom.metaio.unifeye.ndk.IUnifeyeMobileGeometry@4af880
08-28 12:17:01.926: I/AugmentedRealityActivity(5910): modelName unde sunt acuma= movie
08-28 12:17:01.926: I/AugmentedRealityActivity(5910): Model name : movie
08-28 12:17:01.926: I/AugmentedRealityActivity(5910): Got 1 models
08-28 12:17:01.926: I/AugmentedRealityActivity(5910): Returning model : movie
08-28 12:17:01.926: I/AugmentedRealityActivity(5910): model.texture : 'start.png' 
08-28 12:17:01.926: I/System.out(5910): model.texture : 'start.png' 
08-28 12:17:01.926: I/System.out(5910): Pose set : 1
```

And Code for Detection:

```
 @Override
        public void onTrackingEvent(PoseVector poses) {
         for (int i = 0; i < poses.size(); i++) {
            Pose pose = poses.get(i);
            if (pose.isDetected()) {
                ArrayList<MetaioEvent> items = entity.events;
                for (int k = 0; k < items.size(); k++) {
                    MetaioEvent item = items.get(k);
                    Event event = item.event;
                    String type = event.type;
                    String cosName = pose.getCosName() != null ? pose.getCosName().toLowerCase() : "NULL";
                    String cosNameFromFile = event.cosName != null ? event.cosName.toLowerCase() : "NULL";

                    if ("markerDetected".equals(type)) {
                        LogService.log(TAG, ">> Marker detected..");
                        if (!"".equals(cosName) && !"".equals(cosNameFromFile) && cosName.equals(cosNameFromFile)) {
                            System.out.println(">> cosName " + cosName);
                            ArrayList<Action> actions = item.actions;
                            if ((actions != null) && (actions.size() > 0)) {
                                LogService.log(TAG, "Action size in action!=null  ----"+actions.size() + "" + entity.absolutePath );
                                setActions(actions, entity.absolutePath);
                                for (Action action : actions) {
                                    if ((action != null) && (action.type != null)) {
                                        String modelName = action.model;
                                        LogService.log(TAG, "modelName unde sunt acuma= " + modelName);
                                        if ((modelName != null) && (modelName.length() > 0)) {
                                            LogService.log(TAG, "Model name : " + modelName);
                                            MetaioModel model = getModelForName(modelName);
                                            LogService.log(TAG, "model.texture : '" + model.texture + "' ");
                                            System.out.println("model.texture : '" + model.texture + "' ");

                                            IUnifeyeMobileGeometry object = model.model;
                                            String cosName2 = action.cosName;

                                            if ((object != null)) {
                                                if ("camera".equals(cosName2)) {
                                                    object.setCos(0);
                                                    System.out.println("Pose set 0 ");
                                                } else {
                                                    object.setCos(pose.getCosID());
                                                    System.out.println("Pose set : " + pose.getCosID());
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else if (pose.isLost()) {
                for (MetaioEvent item : entity.events) {
                    Event event = item.event;
                    String type = event.type;
                    String cosName = pose.getCosName() != null ? pose.getCosName().toLowerCase() : "NULL";
                    String cosNameFromFile = event.cosName != null ? event.cosName.toLowerCase() : "NULL";

                    if ("markerLost".equals(type)) {
                        LogService.log(TAG, ">> Marker lost..");
                        if (!"".equals(cosNameFromFile) && !"".equals(cosName) && cosName.equals(cosNameFromFile)) {
                            ArrayList<Action> actions = item.actions;
                            if ((actions != null) && (actions.size() > 0)) {
                                setActions(actions, "");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was in the wrong thread, so i did this:

```
if (object != null) {
                            mUnifeyeSurfaceView.queueEvent(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    object.setTexture(texturePath);
                                }
                            });


                            LogService.log(TAG, "Texture set: " + texturePath);
                        } else {
                            LogService.log(TAG, "ERROR: object is null!");
                        }
```